# Systemd ExecStart parameter is not accessible inside the script

Tags: bash, scripts, systemd

I have a very strange situation.

I have a systemd unit

```
[Unit]
Description=Nightly snapshot backup job for [%i] volume

[Service]
Type=simple
KillMode=process
EnvironmentFile=/etc/systemd/schedule-backup_%i.conf
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/backup.sh -s '$SOURCE' -b '$BACKUP' -t '$TITLE' -l 'backup_%i.log'
```

When I execute that with the service instance:
*sudo systemctl start schedule-backup@projects.service*

the backup.sh script does not receive the last parameter at all. It should get "backup_projects.log"

I am reading the parameters with

```
while getopts s:b:t:l: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        s) source_path_root="${OPTARG}";;
        b) backup_path_root="${OPTARG}";;
        t) email_title="${OPTARG}";;
        l) log_name="${OPTARG}";;
    esac
done
```

when I check the service logs, it seems the script is called with the appropriate parameters:

```
systemctl -l status schedule-backup@projects.service -n50

○ schedule-backup@projects.service - Nightly snapshot backup job for [projects] volume
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/schedule-backup@.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2021-12-14 12:47:01 EET; 16min ago
TriggeredBy: ● schedule-backup_projects.timer
    Process: 8161 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/backup.sh -s $SOURCE -b $BACKUP -t $TITLE -l backup_projects.log (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 8161 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 3.122s

Dec 14 12:46:56 fallen-robot systemd[1]: Started Nightly snapshot backup job for [projects] volume.
Dec 14 12:46:56 fallen-robot backup.sh[8161]: /usr/local/bin/backup.sh: line 37: /var/log/: Is a directory
Dec 14 12:46:56 fallen-robot backup.sh[8161]: Log file set to /var/log/
```

When I execute the same script from the console the parameter is accepted fine. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Seems like it worked once I put the -l parameter in the beginning instead of at the end. Could be some problem with getopts. I will accept an answer from whoever can explain this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, systemd is having its own rules for variables from EnvironmentFiles

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd#EnvironmentFiles_and_support_for_.2Fetc.2Fsysconfig_files

It says

> You may then refer to variables set in the /etc/sysconfig/httpd file
> with ${FOOBAR} and $FOOBAR, in the ExecStart= lines (and related
> lines). (${FOOBAR} expands the variable into one word, $FOOBAR splits
> up the variable value at whitespace into multiple words)

After I changed my line to

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/backup.sh -s ${SOURCE} -b ${BACKUP} -t ${TITLE} -l backup_%i.log
```

My problems went away, including one with TITLE that contained white spaces. Without the {} TITLE was expanded to 3 words and since the second and third one appear without '-' to getopts, it will stop further parameter processing and thus ignore the -l backup_%i.log part

> getopts implements the standard option processing, which means that it
> stops looking for options when it either sees an argument that's not
> an option ...

courtesy of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666748/499351